Show two distinct column count in annotate Django
I'm getting trouble with annotate in Django.
I have two models in projects. (just structure)
model A (field:name(char))
model B (field:A(A; related_name="b"), user(user), content(char; null=True))

The data of model B is just like...
row1 -> A:1, user:2, content:"content1"
row2 -> A:1, user:3, content:"content2"
row3 -> A:1, user:2, content:None
row4 -> A:2, user:1, content:None
row5 -> A:1, user:3, content:None

My intention is a unique value that combines user and content according to the pk of model A being searched.
If I look up pk:1 of Model A and the answer I want is 2, and the reason is as follows.
row1 -> A:1, user:2
row2 -> A:1, user:3

So the orginal code was...
subquery = B.objects.filter(a=pk).distinct('user').count()
A.objects.annotate(count=Value(subquery)).get(pk=pk)

However, it is inefficient because it brings up one more query, not inner join.
What should I do?

You say, if you look up pk:1 you want to get 2, but that is because user is different, content as well, but that does not seem to matter much?

Likely this is the X-Y problem: you want to do something (named X), but instead of asking X, you think you will solve it by Y, and thus you ask Y, but Y might not be the best way to fix it. So is it possible to explain what problem you aim to fix?

@willeM_VanOnsem yes. Regardless of the content, I would like to get a count value.

You can move focus to the B model instead:
B.objects.filter(a_id=1).values('user', 'content').distinct().count()

Is there any way to look up in A? You have to do it in A because the actual model A also looks up other values.

@chocho: you can use a in .value(..), or a__content for example, if there is a content in A, but: it does not matter: you filter on A, hence the a_id, or a__content will be fixed if you set a_id=1 for example.

It is very simple answer.
A.objects.annotate(count=Count("b__user", distinct=True)).get(pk=pk)

